# Memoir class forces recto page after \mainmatter

Tags: memoir, double-sided, front-matter

The `memoir`'s `\mainmatter` forces the next page to be a recto page. How can I disable that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: What do you have before `\frontmatter`? I use it as the first command after `\begin{document}`, so the first page is anyway a recto page.

Comment: Sorry, I was supposed to write \mainmatter. Edited

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply patch the command `\mainmatter` to issue a `\clearpage` instead of `\cleardoublepage`.

Insert these lines in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@smemmain}{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@smemmain}{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage}{}{}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum} %only for the example

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@smemmain}{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@smemmain}{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{Intro}
\lipsum[1-10]

\mainmatter

\chapter{1st}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{2nd}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

As you can see the first page after `\mainmatter` is on a verso page and there is not any blank page:

[image]

I hope you are going to use the `memoir`'s option `openany` otherwise the result is ugly...

Comment: Yes, I was already using it. Openany fixes blank pages between chapters, but not the one between frontmatter and mainmatter. Thanks!

Comment: Actually this answer has one problem, which I'd still like to see fixed. If you do double sided printing, and you use a wider margin on the side of the binding, you get the wider margin on the wrong side of the page starting from the mainmatter. You can actually see this problem in your own example. The page with chapter 1 should have the wider margin on the left side of the page.

Comment: @Latex Add `\setlrmargins{*}{*}{0.666} \checkandfixthelayout` right after `\mainmatter`.